# Is ADO.NET Entity Framework (with ASP.NET MVC v2) a viable option when writing custom and contantly updated websites?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I've just finished going through the MvcMusicStore tutorial [found here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples/mvc-music-store). It's an excellent tutorial with working source code. One of my favorite MVC v2 tutorials so far.

That tutorial is my first introduction to using ADO.NET Entity Framework and I must admit that most of it was really quick and straight-forward. However, I am worried about maintainability. How customizable is this framework when the customer requests additional features to their site that require new fields, tables and relationships?

I am very concerned about not being able to efficiently execute customer's change orders because the Entity models are basically drag-and-drop, computer generated code. My experience with code generators is not good. What if something goes haywire in the guts of the model and I'm unable to put humpty-dumpty back together?

In the long run, I wonder if using hand typed models which human-beings can read and edit is a more efficient course than using Entity Framework.

Has anyone worked enough with entity framework to say that they are comfortable using it in a very fluid development environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been using entity framework(V1.0) for about a year in my current project. We have 100s of tables,all added to the edmx. 
Problems we face (though not sure if the new entity framework resolves these issues)

1. When you are used to VS.net IDE, you
   will be used to doing all drag/drop
   operations from your IDE. The
   problem is, once your edmx hosts
   100s of tables,the IDE really stalls
   and you would have to wait for 3-4
   minutes before it becomes responsive
2. With so many tables ,any edits you
   do on the edmx take long.
3. When you are going to use a version
   control, comparing 10000 line XML is
   quite painful. Think about merging 2
   branches each having a 10000 line
   edmx,the tables, new association
   between tables, deleted associations
   and going back and forth comparing
   xmls. You would need a good xml
   comparison tool if you are serious
   about merging 2 big edmx files
4. For performance reasons we had to
   make the csdl,msl and ssdl as
   embedded resources
5. Your edmx should have to be in sync
   with your DB all the time,or at
   least, when you try to update the
   edmx, it will try to sync and might
   throw some obscure errors if they
   are out of sync.
6. Be aware that your
   entities(tables/views) should always
   have a primary key, else you will
   get obscure errors. See my [other
   question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111112/entity-framework-result-discrepancy-for-a-database-views)

Things We did/I might consider in the future when using EF

1. Use multiple edmx by using 1 edmx
       for tables logically grouped/linked
       together. Be aware of the fact that
       if you do this, each edmx should
       live in its own namespace. If you
       try to add 2 related tables(say
       person & address) to 2 edmx in the
       same namespace, you will get a
       compiler error stating that the
       foreign key relationship is already
       defined.  (Tip: create a folder and
       create the edmx under this folder.
       If you try to alter the namespace in
       the edmx without having the folder,
       it does not save properly the
       namespace the next time you
       open/edit it)

   ```
   fewer tables in edmx => less heavy
   container => good
   ```

   fewer tables in edmx=> easier to
   merge when merging 2 branches
2. Be aware of the fact that object
   context is not thread safe
3. Your repository (or what ever DAO you use) should be responsible for creating and disposing the container it creates. Using DI frameworks, especially in a web app complicated things for us. Web requests are served from the threadpool and the container were not disposed properly after the web request was served as the thread itself was not disposed. The container got reused (when the thread was reused) and created a lot of concurrency issues
4. Don't trust your VS IDE. Get a good
   XML editor and know how to edit the
   edmx file (though you don't need to
   edit the designer). Get your hands dirty
5. **ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS** (just cannot emphasize this enough)  run a
   SQL profiler (and I mean each and
   every step of your code) when you
   execute your queries. As complex as
   the query might look, you will be
   surprised to find how many times you
   hit the DB Example:(sorry, unable to
   get code to the right format,can
   someone format it ?)

   ```
   var myOrders = from t in context.Table where t.CustomerID=123
   ```

   select t; //above query not yet
   executed

   `if(myOrders.Count>0)//DB query to
   find count    {
       var firstOrder = myOrders.First()//DB query to get
   first result
       }`

   Better approach

   // query materialized, just 1 hit to
   DB as we are using ToList()   var
   myOrders = (from t in Context.tables
   where t.customerID=123 select
   t).ToList();

   ```
   if(myOrders.Count>0)//no DB hit
   {
   //do something
   var myOrder = myOrders[0];//no DB hit
   }
   ```
6. Know when to use tracking and no
   tracking(for read-only) and web apps
   do a lot of reads than writes. Set
   them properly when you initialize
   your container
7. Did I forget compiled queries ? Look
   [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/speedinguplinqtosql.aspx) for more goodies
8. When getting 1000s of rows back from
   your DB, make sure you  use IQueryable and [detach the
   objectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738697.aspx) so that you don't
   run out of memory

**Update:**

[Julie Lerman](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/) address the same problem with a [similar solution](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/creating-models-from-databases-with-billions-of-tables/). Her post also points to [Ward](http://www.ideablade.com/WardsCorner/WardsCorner_home.aspx)'s work on  dealing with [huge number of tables](http://www.ideablade.com/WardsCorner/LargeEFModels.pdf)

Comment: one other informative post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547278/what-are-good-design-practices-when-working-with-entity-framework

Comment: @Ram - Thanks a ton for such a detailed post. I can't really tell if you're advocating using entity or not because you're using EF but you list a few problems/headaches that you've had. You also of course post tips to avoid those problems (because I'm new to EF a lot of it is greek to me as of yet.) Overall, are you saying it's worth it to implement the new technology in a fast-paced, custom setting?

Comment: Go for it.Go for the latest one.And I would be curious to see if I can use T4 (though not sure if I can customize the SQL which is getting fired). Always watch over the queries(and the left joins) when you do a "include" on your objectContext.Table. Update your knowledge with books/blogs and ofcourse StackOverflow. Few months down the lane, you will be a EF geek !! Good Luck

Comment: [Don't use Count when you mean Any](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/04/21/38598/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with Entity Framework, but I believe it simply generates an EDM file which can be hand-edited.  I know I've done this quite frequently with the Linq-to-SQL DBML files that the designer generates (it's often faster to hand-edit them than use the designer for small tweaks).

Comment: There is a code-behind that is called foo.Designer.cs. This file can be hand edited but it is a mammoth file. I'm not sure how realistic it is to be messing with that code. I have humpty-dumpty/kings men nightmares.

Comment: @quakkels - So there isn't an XML file with the entity mappings in it?  There is a designer file for Linq-to-SQL as well, but editing the associated XML file causes the designer file to be automatically regenerated.

Comment: I don't see an xml. I could be looking in the wrong place but there is foo.edmx file and when i expand that structure in the solution explorer it reveals the C# code-behind.

Comment: @quakkels - Try right-clicking on the foo.edmx file and doing an "Open with" -> "XML Editor"

Answer (score 1):

You know I'd be interested if any developers can provide some insight into this.
Any Entity Framework examples seem to only consist of about ten to twenty tables, which is small scale really.

What about using the EF on a database with hundreds or even a thousand tables?

Personally, I know several developers and organisations that were burned by LINQ-to-SQL and are holding off for a year or so to see what direction EF takes.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Entity Framework 4 (with Visual Studio 2010), the generated code is outputted from T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) files which you can edit so you have full control over what is generated. See [Oleg Sych's blog](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/) which is a mine of information about T4. Code generation is not a problem and T4 opens so many perspectives that I can't live without anymore.

I'm currently working on a project where we use Entity Framework 4 for the data access layer, and Scrum as the agile project management method. From one sprint to another, there are several tables added, other modified, new requirements added. When you have run once into each potential EF problem (like knowing that default values from database are not persisted by default in the .edmx file, or changing a nullable column to a non-nullable and updating the designer doesn't change the mapped property state), you're good to go.

**Edit:** to answer your question, it's EF 4 whose code generation is based on T4 rather than T4 supporting EF. On EF 3.5 (or EF 1.0 if you prefer), you could in theory use T4 by writing them from scratch, parsing the EDMX file in the T4 code and generate your entities. It would be quite a lot of work considering all of this is already done by EF 4. Plus, Entity Framework 3.5 only supports one type of entitiy, whereas EF 4 as built in or downloadable templates for POCO entities (that don't know anything about persistence), Self-Tracking Entities...

Considering Entity Framework itself, I think it was lacking many features in its first release, and while usable, was quite frustrating to use. EF4 is much more improved. It still lacks some basic features (like enum support), but it has become my data access layer of choice now.

Comment: Julien:Does T4 have support for EF 1.0 ?