# Entity Framework Problems: Retrieving cached values instead of recent changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, caching

I have a stored procedure that loops through a table and it may insert some records in to that table .  Its working fine . I can see the changes in db using management studio .

The problem is after that i will call another stored procedure which will return a collection .But it always return a cached value or something like that .The latest changes in db not reflecting in the returned list .Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I am importing stored procedure to function using EF. All the operations i made is via EF. 
Chek following code

```
 TraktorumEntities db = new TraktorumEntities();
var test= db.GetAvailableAttributes(CategoryID).ToList(); // here i get cached values  .How can i force to fetch data from data base
```

Comment: This is the problem of ORM. Once you use stored procedure which make changes outside of ORM, ORM doesn't know about them and you must explicitly force it to reload data. Try @Adam's sugestion with `MergeOption`. If it doesn't work use a new context to execute second stored procedure.

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547278/what-are-good-design-practices-when-working-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are querying using the same key, EF will have your results cached.

Note the section of "MergeOption.OverwriteChanges" here

[Walkthrough: Mapping an Entity to Stored Procedures (Entity Data Model Tools)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716679.aspx)
You need to tell EF to 'get new data and overwrite the locally stored version' with this option.

Also you don't really tell us exactly how you are querying this data either. Is this a mapped stored procedure (mapped to an entity operation) or calling it directly on the context, or....?

**EDIT**
Try something along these lines

```
var test= db.GetAvailableAttributes(CategoryID)
test.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
var results = test.ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you leave some Database.SetInitializer in the Global Application_Start?

Comment: No .I am no using anything like that