# ADO.NET Entity OrderBy VS. View Order By?

Tags: performance, ado.net, entity, sql-order-by

Recently I am doing ADO.NET entity programming, I noticed for each entity it has **OrderBy** method, however consider about performance, should I create a **View** with **Order By** in database rather than use **OrderBy** in entity?

In my thought, the entity will return all the resultset from database into the memory first then do the sort, however the **View** from database will do the sort on database level and return the sorted resultset back. If in that case, the second way will be better, am I right?

Correct me if I am wrong :-)

Thanks.

Comment: After further investigation with SQL Server Profiler, I can confirm the ADO.NET Entity Framework is smart enough to convert your code to the proper SQL criteria (e.g. OrderBy("it.FirstName").Take(5) will be convert to SELECT TOP 5 * FROM xxx ORDER BY FirstName). The performance is no doubt to be the good as native SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I have limited experience with Entity Framework but `order by` does not work in views (see [this post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/23/sql-server-order-by-does-not-work-limitation-of-the-views-part-1/)).

There appears to be some great information regarding Entity Framework best practices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547278/what-are-good-design-practices-when-working-with-entity-framework). You may also look into using SQL Profiler to see the queries executed at runtime run against the SQL server or using an Entity Framework profiler as described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx).